# Gitlab Ci: pass artifacts on failure to manual job

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

I have a stage that tries to make a terraform plan.
On failure, I want to pass the output to another job that can be manually run.
I tried the following:

```yaml
plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    # If failed, store the output in a file (used for manual clean up).
    - set -o pipefail; terraform plan -out=$PLAN 2>&1 | tee error.out
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - error.out
    when: always

manual force unlock:
  stage: unlock
  script:
    # Nb: busybox's grep is limited 
    - terraform force-unlock -force $(grep -e 'ID:.*' error.out | grep -o "[^ ]*$")
  needs:
    - job: master plan
      artifacts: true
      optional: true
  when: manual
```

But it always get skipped. If I don't have the "optional", it may break the pipeline because in reality, the "plan" job can only run on production branches (only: ["main"])

I tried multiple variations with `dependencies`. Note that I initially wanted the "manual force unlock" job to be in the same stage as the "plan" job.

Any idea?

I tried multiple combinaison of "dependencies", "needs" key words, I also tried with the cache, ...
Nothing worked.

I found somethin similar but unsolved:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-provide-manual-option-when-a-job-is-failed/71478

Answer (score 0):

[By default](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/20280) a manual job can only be started when all jobs on which the manual job depends have completed successfully. So it is not possible to combine `when: manual` and `when: on_failure` behavior.

It is also not possible to configure a job via the `gitlab-ci` file to download artifacts from jobs that the job does not depend on.

According to above restrictions - one of a possible ways will be to make the `plan` job [allow_failure:true](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure):

```
plan:
  stage: plan
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - error.out
    when: always

manual-force-unlock:
  stage: plan
  script:
    ...
  needs:
    - job: plan
      optional: true
  when: manual
```

In this case - it will be still visible that the `plan` job failed via an orange warning sign and the `manual-force-unlock` will be available to run manually. Also it is possible to have these jobs on the same stage. But the limitation is that the pipeline will finish with success.